concentration of norm of non-central Gaussian around its mean
Let $a\in \mathbb{R}^d$ be a fixed vector. Let $X_1,\dots, X_n$ be $n$ iid samples from $\mathcal{N}(0,\mathbb{I}_d)$ (multivariate Gaussian with identity covariance). I am interested in characterizing $t$ and $\beta$ such that
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Pr}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left( \lVert X_i - a \rVert - \mathbb{E}_{X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\mathbb{I}_d)}\left[\lVert X - a \rVert \right]\right) \geq t \right)\leq \beta.
\end{equation}
Context: This question arises for analyzing the connection between empirical geometric median and the population geometric median.

I think you can directly use the fact that $|X_i - a|$ are sub-exponential random variables and then use the standard concentration inequalities for those.

Sudeep's suggestion would readily provide you with a concentration inequality, albeit one that likely depends on the ambient dimension $d$.

Let $f(X) := \sum_{i = 1}^n \|X_i - a\|$. We first prove that $f$ is $\sqrt{n}$-Lipschitz:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(X) - f(Y) &= \sum_{i = 1}^n \|X_i - a\| - \|Y_i - a\| \\
&\leq
\sum_{i = 1}^n \|X_i - Y_i\| && (\text{triangle inequality})\\
&= n \cdot \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{n} \cdot \sqrt{\|X_i - Y_i\|^2} \\
&\leq n \cdot \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n \|X_i - Y_i\|^2}
&& (\text{Jensen inequality}) \\
&= \sqrt{n} \cdot \|X - Y\|_{\mathsf{F}},
\end{aligned}
$$
where $X = \begin{pmatrix} X_1 & \dots & X_{n} \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times n}$ and $Y$ is defined similarly and $\|A\|_{\mathsf{F}}$ denotes the Frobenius norm. A completely symmetric argument yields $f(Y) - f(X) \leq \sqrt{n} \cdot \|X - Y\|_{\mathsf{F}}$.
You can now use things like the Gaussian-Lipschitz concentration inequality (e.g., Theorem 5.2.2 here) to deduce concentration of $f$ around its mean.
